# Discord bot Client not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot and I am running in to a problem:

```
ReferenceError: Client is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arya\Desktop\Arya\Discord\bot.js:3:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

the code is

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Cient, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
intent: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
 ]
});

bot.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: It's `const { Client` not `const { Cient`, and it's `client.login`, not `bot.login`, and it's `intents: ` not `intent: `. Make sure you fix your typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple syntax error, this works:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
]
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Your login at the bottom confuses me where the bot variable is but if my code does not work you can change it back. Otherwise you just needed to add a s to intent.

Comment: Typos are not always SyntaxErrors, and in this case it's a ReferenceError instead

Answer (score 0):

- You are defining `Cient` instead of `Client` in the second line of your code
- The client options must specify `intents: [ YOUR_INTENTS_HERE ]` instead of `intent`
- The last line must be `client.login` instead of `bot.login`